# Разбивка текста по два слова

Tags: javascript, массивы, регулярные-выражения, строки, циклы

#### Вопрос:

У меня есть переменная в которой содержится произвольная строка типа `"lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur"`. Нужно разбить этот текст по два слова, что бы в конечном результате превратить эту строку в массив `["lorem ipsum", "dolor sit", "amet consectetur"]`.

Поскольку текст в переменной может быть любой, то этот скрипт должен автоматически разделять строку по два слова и превращать ее в массив.

#### PS:

Я думаю, что нужно взять стоку, и с помощью метода `replace(' ', ';')` заменить каждый второй пробел на `;`. А потом с помощью метода `split(';')` превратить строку в массив и разделить ее по знаку `;`. Но я не знаю как заменить каждый второй пробел.

Comment: а если будет нечетное количество слов?

Comment: остаток должен отбрасываться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно разбить текст на слова, а потом в цикле объединить слова в пары:

```
var result = splitToPairs("lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur");

function splitToPairs(input) {
  var words = input.split(" ");
  var pairs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i += 2) {
      pairs.push(words[i] + " " + words[i+1]);
  }
  return pairs;
}
```